# How can i update metadata of cnft

Tags: cnft, helius

i have minted a cnft using helius api. I would like now to update the metadata. If i understood well, they are stored offchain (arweave via helius), but i guess the link to the arweave file must be onchain like regular nft no ?

Do you know how can we update these metadata ?

Answer (score 0):

here is a link with instructions for updating the metadata: https://docs.helius.dev/compression-and-das-api/mint-api#update-metadata

full disclosure: i work at helius